# How to solve this equation with ceiling function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given that $x$ is a positive integer, find $x$ in $(E)$.

$$\tag{E} j-n=x-n\cdot\left\lceil\frac{x}{n}\right\rceil$$
All $n, j, x$ are positive integers.

Comment: solve for x? for j ?

Comment: what's "E" here ?

Comment: ($E$) is simply a label for the equation. The OP wants to solve for $x$.

Comment: hint:if $n|x$ then ,not solvable for x $$x=nk+0\\j-n=x-n.k\\j-n=x-x=0$$ now take $x=nk+r\\r>0 \\\frac{x}{n}=\frac{nk+r}{n}=k+\frac{k}{n}\\\left \lceil \frac{x}{n} \right \rceil=k+1$

Comment: @daryakhosrotash: If you set $j=n$, then the solutions are _exactly_ the multiples of $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  $n\cdot\left\lceil\frac{x}{n}\right\rceil$ is $x$ rounded up to the next multiple of $n$, so the right side of your equation is just $x \bmod n-n$ unless $n|x$ in which case it is zero.

Comment: Is "$x\pmod n$" instead of "$x\bmod n$" (with `\bmod`) a typo?

Comment: Except when $n\mid x$ -- then the right hand side is $0$ rather than $-n$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  I use \pmod and didn't know about \bmod.  I don't see the difference.

Comment: `\bmod` produces a binary _operator_, whereas `\pmod` adds a set of parentheses and spacing to make it work as the last part of the three-place _relation_ $\mathit{blah}\equiv\mathit{blah}\pmod n$. Writing "$x\pmod n$" inserts an opening parenthesis between the first operand and the operator, which is not how binary operators are supposed to be written.

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  thanks.  I didn't know that.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: it may help to get rid of the ceiling function by using the division algorithm and letting $x = kn + a$ for some minimal $a$.

Answer (score 0):

1st step
   $n|x$ then ,not solvable for x $$x=nk+0\\j-n=x-n.k\\j-n=x-x=0 \rightarrow j=n \\x=nk \\x=jk \\$$so $x$ is an integer that divide by n
2nd step :
 now take $$x=nk+r\\0<r<n \\\frac{x}{n}=\frac{nk+r}{n}=k+\frac{r}{n}\\\left \lceil \frac{x}{n} \right \rceil=k+1\\j-n=x-n(k+1)\\j-n=(nk+r)-n(k+1)\\j-n=r-n\\j=r\\x=nk+j , j<n$$